# Jenkins error on building command?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins, starting now.
I see the following errors here.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GIF_DECODER
[GIF_DECODER] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson3370393570271110742.sh
/tmp/hudson3370393570271110742.sh: line 2: cd: /home/joshis1/Data/E-Drive/Blog/Ready_to_post/Ubuntu/GIF_Decoder_LINUX: Permission denied
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GIF_DECODER
```

I have given the build commands as the following. This is under execute shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/joshis1/Data/E-Drive/Blog/Ready_to_post/Ubuntu/GIF_Decoder_LINUX 
pwd
make clean
make everything
```

I am not understanding what is the issue here? Looks to be a permission year. I have jenkins in sudoers list. I don't why it looks for /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GIF_Decoder.

I see the jenkins page under - http://:8080/job/GIF_DECODER/configure

How can I setup the hostname so that instead of localhost I have some meaningful name? Please help. Also, what is the best document/video to start with Jenkins for linux users? How to debug Jenkins issue seen? How can I instantiate a build by sending an email?

Answer (score 0):

**I am not understanding what is the issue here?**
It's a permission error. It looks like your jenkins user does not have permissions for `/home/joshis1/Data/E-Drive/Blog/Ready_to_post/Ubuntu/GIF_Decoder_LINUX`

**How can I setup the hostname so that instead of localhost I have some meaningful name?**
Try the hostname of your server in the URL. e.g. `http://myserver:8080/job/GIF_DECODER/configure`

**Also, what is the best document/video to start with Jenkins for linux users?**
I expect that you have a basic understanding of how linux works. This is important on how to configure your jenkins and write the necessary build steps. The most basic information you will find on http://jenkins-ci.org and basic installation https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins

**How to debug Jenkins issue seen?**
That depends ...
... on the issue. If you have build problems check the console output of the job first. In addition, Jenkins writes its logfiles into the jenkins home directory.

**How can I instantiate a build by sending an email?**
Check out the [mail commander plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mail+Commander+Plugin)